# Change my select options when click on radio button with mysql and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, radio-button

```
<form action="naam.php" method="POST">

<input type="radio" name="gender"value="female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="gender"value="male">Male</input>

<label>Voornaam: </label>
<select name="owner">
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT firstname FROM employers ");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<option>" . $row['firstname'] . "</option>";
}
?>
<br />
</select>
<button>bekijk</button>
</form>
```

I want to change my options list when i click on the radio button with MySQL and PHP.

Someone code?

Comment: So, you want the user to click either male or female and depending on what they click, the dropdown shows either male or female names?

Comment: We are not your work monkeys, come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side, not in the users browser. So you need to submit your form after the user choose a radio button. Let PHP fetch your names from the database and display them to the user on the following page.

Or, output both male and female select boxes and hide them via CSS. Then use JavaScript to enable display again based on what the user clicked.